# Splitting a file-like String inti strings in Java

Tags: java, string

Does anyone know how to split a string like this (where there is a newline every two words):

```
String str =  "word1 word2
               word3 word4
                 ....
               word100 word101"
```

into [word1, word2, word3, word4,....,word100,word101] ?

I have tried str.split(" ") but it doesn't work since it gives a bad length for the resulting array of words ?

Comment: What is the actual error that you are given?

Comment: for a 3 level string for example I got a length of 4 instead of 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newlines and spaces are both "whitespace", so:

```
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
```

`\s` being the regex for whitespace, and `+` meaning "one or more".